# jQuery animate not adjusting correctly

Tags: jquery, css

I've written some JavaScript to resize a menu-bar, however the code does not return the correct values. It adds `height:147px; min-height:70px;` in the `style` attribute of the element, when scrolling downwards. However, I want height to be `70px` too.

For testing I tried to change it in the Chrome Debugger. However, every time I changed it, it directly changes back. Here is the code:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).width() > 900) {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scrollTop > 45) {
            $('#wpadminbar').fadeOut();
            $( ".bottom_bar" ).addClass( "stickymenu" );
            $('.bottom_bar').stop().animate({height: "70px"},300);
            $('.bottom_bar').stop().animate({minHeight: "70px"},300);
            $('.bottom_bar.menuwrapper').stop().animate({lineHeight: "70px"},300);
            $('.bottom_bar.menuwrapper').stop().animate({height: "70px"},300);
        }
        else {
            $('#wpadminbar').fadeIn();
            $( ".bottom_bar" ).removeClass( "stickymenu" );
            $('.bottom_bar').stop().animate({height: "147px"},300);
            $('.bottom_bar').stop().animate({minHeight: "147px"},300);
            $('.bottom_bar.menuwrapper').stop().animate({lineHeight: "147px"},300);
            $('.bottom_bar.menuwrapper').stop().animate({height: "147px"},300);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way this code is written, the animation in the top line is going to stop immediately because the second line will run at the same time (not after the 300ms animation), and stop any ongoing animations.

```
$('.bottom_bar').stop().animate({height: "70px"},300);
$('.bottom_bar').stop().animate({minHeight: "70px"},300);
```

Combine both lines into one to fix this, like so:

```
$('.bottom_bar').stop().animate({height: "70px", minHeight: "70px"},300);
```

Do this for all pairs in your example and see if this fixes the issue.